# error LNK2038 mismatch detected

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cygwin

I am trying to run a code using Geant4 (A physics library) and trying to compile it on VS2010.
It seems that some libraries of Geant4 have problem matching with my C++ libraries. In compilation I get a huge number of similar errors like the following:

> libG4Tree.a(G4ASCIITree.o) : error LNK2038 : mismatch detected for
>   '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL' : value '0' doesn't match value '2' in
>   Workshopexample1.OBJ

And get this error with more than 100 different .a files in my G4 libraries. 
I really need the debug level to be off ('0'). Since otherwise G4 codes will take years to be run. So, I need to find where is this `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` defined in my VS2010 and set it to '0' to avoid mismatching. Can anybody help?
Cheers,
Payam

Comment: Are you saying your trying to use Cygwin (gcc) built DLLs with VS2k10 Windows DLLs?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985939%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The error can be caused by mixing together debug builds and release builds in same executable or dll.

Release version of the static lib with /MDd instead of /MD, whereas the application is /MD in release. Setting the correct /MD in the static lib project solved the issue.

This is done in Project properties

```
Select Configuration Properties / C C++ / Code Generation in the tree
and the option Runtime Library set to the same on all your dependencies projects and application.
```

Search for _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL and _SECURE_SCL remove them or set them appropriately in all projects and sources and rebuild everything.

```
_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL = 0 // disabled (for release builds)
_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL = 1 // enabled (if _SECURE_SCL is defined)
_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL = 2 // enabled (for debug builds)
```

In short you are probably mixing release and debug dlls. Don't linked release dlls in debug or vice versa!